# C++ exception class with printf style string?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, is there an easy (or even better, built-in) way to do something like this to do printf-style strings in an exception?

```
throw std::runtime_error( "Failed to open '%s' [%d]: %s", 
         filename, errno, strerror(errno) );
```

I know I could `snprintf` to a `char []' then pass the result into an exception constructor with or w/o converting to std::string first.

Just wondering if C++11 has anything better/simpler to offer.

Comment: You  might want boost::format (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/) or something simpler.

Comment: Easy to implement your own with vsnprintf, but dangerous to use. A formatting error or overrun inside an exception would be a horror to behold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++11, you can construct exceptions from an `std::string`:

```
std::runtime_error("Failed to open " + std::string(filename) + std::to_string(errno));
```

This has the slight drawback that the constructor of `std::string` might `throw` and thus terminate your program. However, this should only come into play while handling some kind of "out of memory" exception.

Comment: Won't throwing an exception *always* allocate memory?

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Even if it is statically allocated you will need some space because you always throw a copy of the exception. That usually does not need any heap allocations afaik, and an `std::string` is potentially *really* big. But I never ran into problems with this in real world code and just mentioned this to get a complete answer.

Comment: Ok, I think in my case that's an acceptable risk but good to have in mind.  Using `+` for concatenation was my first thought for simple strings, but I didn't know about `to_string`, and thought `ostringstream` would be awkward.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just talking about creating the formatted string, you can use concatenation with [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to open ") + filename +  "[" + std::to_string(errno) + "]: " + strerror(errno));
```